# In pyiron how to move some jobs to a different project?

Tags: pyiron

In the project I'm working on right now, I realized that it makes more sense to move some of the jobs to a sub-group (which I just discovered with `pr.create_group`). I see that `pr.move_to` or `pr.copy_to` moves all jobs to a new project, but is there also a possibility to move some jobs to one sub-group and others to another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job objects also have a `move_to()` function, so I would suggest to iterate over the jobs in a given project using `iterjobs()` and then move them individually. This even works in `inspect` mode https://github.com/pyiron/pyiron_base/blob/master/pyiron_base/job/core.py#L757